# How do I get Typescript to recognize a Number as a number?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to do some simple math with what should be a number returned from a request.ReponseText and a number entered into a textbox. Here is the code

```
//var storedMiles : number = new Number(request.responseText);
var storedMiles = new Number(request.responseText);
var enteredMiles = parseInt((<HTMLTextAreaElement>document.getElementById("txtMiles")).value);
var intervalMiles = (enteredMiles - storedMiles);
```

The error that I am getting from the TypeScript compiler is:

```
The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.
```

The compiler is putting the squiggly line under the `enteredMiles` in the `var intervalMiles = (enteredMiles - storedMiles);` line.

I wasn't able to find anything in the documentation about how to correct that error. Nor have I found a way to do the conversion myself. What is needed for the TypeScript compiler to treat both the `enteredMiles` and the `storedMiles` as the same "type" of number so I can do the math?

Comment: I have no idea about TypeScript, but isn't `storedMiles` an object? Why don't you use `parseInt` on `responseText` as well?

Comment: Does `var storedMiles: number = +request.responseText` work?

Comment: Prinzhorn I originally did try to put the parstInt on the storedMiles but I did it wrong. I tried parseInt( new Number(request.responseText) ); and couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because Number is not the same as number. The following will fix it:

```
var storedMiles = parseInt(request.responseText);
```

Complete code (also with radix as steve pointed out):

```
var storedMiles = parseInt(request.responseText,10);
var enteredMiles = parseInt((<HTMLTextAreaElement>document.getElementById("txtMiles")).value,10);
var intervalMiles = (enteredMiles - storedMiles);
```

**More Explanation:**

Here is some code to show you a basic difference between Number and number:

```
var num = 3;
var Num = new Number(3); 

console.log(typeof num); // number 
console.log(typeof Num); // object
```

[Try it](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=var%20num%20=%203;%0Avar%20Num%20=%20new%20Number%283%29;%20%0A%0Aconsole.log%28typeof%20num%29;%20//%20number%20%0Aconsole.log%28typeof%20Num%29;%20//%20object%20)

Comment: Don't forget to pass a radix argument to parseInt to avoid accidental mis-interpretation of data... parseInt(myString, 10) - this prevents ECMAScript 3 browsers interpreting numbers starting with 0 as octal.

Comment: Thanks Steve, added. I was just being lazy :)